# Результат выполнения switch

Tags: java

результатом выполнения `switch (x)` является число 4241, я ожидал число 42, как можно остановить переход от одного `case` к другому ?

```
   int x = 42;
    switch (x) {
    case 43: System.out.print("4241");
    case 42: System.out.print("42");
    case 41: System.out.print("41");
    }
```

Comment: `результатом выполнения этого переключателя является число 42414241` это же не так

Comment: да, извиняюсь получается другое число

Comment: Я протестировал, выводит 42, а не 4241, поэтому я не понял суть вопроса

Comment: Ваша правка исказила вопрос, теперь он не имеет смысла.

Comment: так, я вернул так как было, ответ 4241 теперь же верно?

Comment: @Daniil проставьте break после каждого case.

Comment: В общем,я так понял, вопрос был решен. Надеюсь вы поняли суть проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит потому что после выполнения одного `case` выполнение переходит к следующему.

Правильно так:

```
int x = 42;
switch (x) {
case 43: 
    System.out.print("4241");
    break;
case 42: 
    System.out.print("42");
    break;
case 41: 
    System.out.print("41");
    break;
}
```